# Beamer listings fragile -- Too much space

Tags: beamer, spacing

I am using `listings` package in Beamer. 
If I use inline listing, there is no problem and the listings look good.
However, if I use `\begin{lstlisting}`, it is required to use fragile frame and the listings become urly. Too much space between characters.

Attached are the minimal running example and the output that describe my problem.

Much appreciated if you can help me to fix this.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usecolortheme{crane}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=HTML,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  breaklines=true
}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Question -- Beamer-Listings-Fragile}

Inline listing, good looking: 
\lstinline!<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="filename"/>!

\vspace{4ex}
Too much space for this:
\begin{lstlisting}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="filename"/>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The options `aboveskip` and `belowskip` control the spacing around `lstlisting` environments.  By default they are `medskip` but you can set them to zero.  If doing this with a `\lstset` command in `beamer` this needs to be *after* `\begin{document}`.  The additional letter spacing in the environment is standard behaviour of `listings`; set `columns=flexible` to change this (see the package documentation for other variations):

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usecolortheme{crane}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=HTML,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  breaklines=true,
  columns=flexible
}

\begin{document}
\lstset{aboveskip=0pt, belowskip=0pt}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Question -- Beamer-Listings-Fragile}

Inline listing, good looking: 
\lstinline!<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="filename"/>!

\vspace{4ex}
Was too much space for this:
\begin{lstlisting}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="filename"/>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```